# Converting a SQL Server trigger to PostgreSQL trigger problems with the trigger function

Tags: postgresql

I am in the middle of converting an existing SQL Server 2005 DB into a PostgreSQL 9.0 DB.

Everything works fine until now. I want to translate a SQL trigger into PostgreSQL but I have a problem with the trigger function.

I don't know how to implement the temp table `inserted` in the PostgreSQL syntax. In SQL Server the `inserted` table exists but not in PostgreSQL. Any ideas?

My code (PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_co_insert()

  RETURNS trigger AS

$BODY$begin

  declare

  aa bigint;

begin

  select aa = co_id from inserted;

  update com03 set co_creationdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  co_creationby = USER where co_id = aa;

end;

end;
```

---

Here the code of the trigger body of the SQL Server 2005 code

```
begin

    declare @aa bigint;

    select @aa = se_id from inserted;

    update server set se_creationdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , se_creationby = USER where se_id = @aa;

end;
```

thanks

Chris

Answer (score 3):

The default in PostgreSQL is a row level trigger (as opposed to SQL Server where it's a statement level trigger), so there is no need for an "inserted" table to select from.

The new and old values can be accessed using the keyword `new` and `old` (old does not exist for an insert trigger).

In your case the statement would simply be:

```
  update com03 
       set co_creationdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
       co_creationby = CURRENT_USER
  where co_id = new.co_id;
```

No need to "select from inserted".

This assumes the trigger is **not** firing for the table `com03`. If your trigger fires for `com03` (which you didn't tell us), then it' even easier:

```
  new.co_creationdate := current_timestamp;
  new.co_creationby := current_user;
```

For details please refer to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

That page also contains an example which does exactly what you are trying to achieve